# Как сделать, чтобы при записи в файл строки сразу появлялись в файле

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы добавляемые в текстовый файл строки методом `file.write()` отображались сразу в файле, а не ожидать `file.close()`?

Скрипт строки добавляет в txt, но отображаются они только в конце работы.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь 'file.flush()'

Comment: @MaxU после каждого file.write() делать file.flush? он как я понял актуализирует информацию в file

Comment: Если строка содержит новую строку, можно  line_buffering включить (buffering=1)

Comment: @jfs file.write (line, buffering=1) верно?

Comment: Нет. Режим буферизации один для всего файла: [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, работает как нужно!

Comment: @dimahimma если думаете, что нашли решение, вы можете свой ответ добавить, чтобы помочь другим людям с похожей проблемой — [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs готово..............

Answer (score 0):

Если строка содержит новую строку, можно `line_buffering` включить `buffering=1`
Режим буферизации один для всего файла: `open()`